# Android Studio : HTML5 Webapp to APK using webview, error your browser does not allow to be read local files

Tags: android, html, android-studio, web-applications

I'm trying to get my html5 webapp converted to apk using android studio. I'm able to compile it but i get the error your browser does not allow to be read local files.

the only permissions in my manifest are

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

EDIT: I Can't seem to get the syntax correct

```
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

i tried view.settings but that immediately throws an error

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly allow it in the WebView.

Example.

```
    webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  can you check my code at the top?

Answer (score 0):

view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);